# Operator-- in Linked List

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list

I am trying to overload operator-- in a singly linked list.

I have a node class with:
T info 
nodeType *link

Iterator class (which is a friend to singly linked list) with:
nodeType *first
nodeType *current
bool offTheEdge

Singly Linked List class with:
*first
*last

I have successfully modified the operator++ method and i am passing all the tests. The code is as follows:

```
if(offTheEdge == true)
{
    return *this;
}
else
{
    if(current->link == NULL)
    {
        offTheEdge = true;
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        current = current->link;
    }
}

return *this;
```

My instructions are as follows:
Same as the operator++, but going backwards. Going backwards in a singly linked list
means you have to start from the beginning, and identify the node behind where this->current is.

Please help, no matter what i try i am unable to get the previous elements and work backwards. Thank you!

My code for operator-- is:

```
ListIterator<T> temp;

temp.current = first;

while(temp.current->link != this->current)
{
    temp.current = temp.current->link;
}

return temp;
```

If my list is 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20....it returns 20 everytime

Comment: Your instructions basically tell you exactly what to do.  Have you tried "you have to start from the beginning, and identify the node behind where this->current is"? Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Just iterate through the whole list util `current->link == oldCurrent`

Comment: In other words you'll have to start at the `head` and use a loop.

Comment: At the start of the method: first is the first node and current is the last node. i created a temp iterator object and started at first and when until temp.current->link == current. This gave me what i wanted but when i returned temp, it returned current.

Comment: Do you really need the -- operator?

Comment: yes it is a TODO method of my homework. I have completed all required methods except for the operator- and the operator-- because i cannot figure out how to get the previous node. The directions basically say operator- and operator-- are exactly like operator+ and operator++(which i have completed) but i just can't figure out how to go backwards using this->current?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the actual iterator doesn't change in your code. In your operator++ code you have `current = current->link`, but in operator-- you only alter the temporary iterator(i.e.
`this->current` never actually changes).